# How to deploy Iceberg tables to AWS through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, apache-iceberg

trying to determine the best ways to deploy some Iceberg tables into our AWS environment. Has anyone had success via Terraform? I have the following configuration, but Athena complains of lacking metadata location (or will just spin forever) when I query the table I created. If there are better ways that can be automated for deployment, please let me know as this could just be a limit in the provider.

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "iceberg-table" {

  name          = "sales_header"
  database_name = "sales"

  # Governed tables require this value in uppercase.
  parameters = {
    "table_type" = "ICEBERG"
    "format"     = "parquet"
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    location      = "s3://${var.s3_raw_bucket}/sales/sales_header/"

    columns {
      name    = "transaction_id"
      type    = "integer"
      comment = ""
    }
    columns {
      name    = "sale_date"
      type    = "integer"
      comment = ""
    }
    columns {
      name    = "sale_amount"
      type    = "float"
      comment = ""
    }
  }
}
```

Tried running the attached code block, presented with errors.

Comment: Does this help: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-real-time-gdpr-aligned-apache-iceberg-data-lake/? More as an example than a complete solution and maybe there are steps you need to undertake to make it work.

Comment: No, that's a manual deployment in their article. Our teams aren't allowed to manually deploy to higher environments, it needs to be IaC or programmatic.

Comment: I meant do you need to activate the Iceberg connector for Glue from the Marketplace first, not that you do it manually.

Comment: If I don't remember wrong I tried the same thing and it complains about lacking metadata location because the glue table defined points to a metadata file that was not created in S3. I guess the terraform provider is not prepared for building the `.metadata.json` file.

Comment: @pauetpupa - exactly one of the errors I've gotten. From what I've seen it looks like Athena and possibly the CLI are the only viable options for deploying Iceberg tables right now.

Answer (score 1):

We're deploying iceberg tables using terraform and are able to query them from athena. We've got a couple of things that are missing in the example above:

```
  table_type = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  open_table_format_input {
    iceberg_input {
      metadata_operation = "CREATE"
    }
  }
```

There's more on both of those in the terraform [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_catalog_table)